# Storing ajax jquery into a variable and acessing it with the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can I call jquery ajax from a variable like this ?

```
var save = $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'json',
   url: "functions/ajaxInsertCheck.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
      alert(response.a);

   }

 // call ajax jquery
 save
```

How can I call that request like its a function? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a **function**. Functions encapsulate behavior we will want to invoke in the future. You can pass functions **arguments** which indicate how you want the function to execute.

Functions are typically used when we want to have reusable bits in our code or for code clarity:

```
function save(){ // declare a function and call it save
  return $.ajax({ // a return means we're letting people from the outside use it
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "functions/ajaxInsertCheck.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
      alert(response.a);
    }
 });
}
```

Then you can call it from your own code:

```
save(); // call the save function performing this action.
```

Note that there are plenty of examples of functions already in your code like `alert` and `$.ajax` that were defined by you by the browser and jQuery respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, can you defer execution of the call as you've written it, then no.  The call is executed immediately.

Check out the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - particularly under the heading "The jqXHR Object".  It's different depending on the version of JQuery, but you get back an object that implements the Promise interface.

But using javascript features, you can make a function:

```
function saveFunction() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       dataType: 'json',
       url: "functions/ajaxInsertCheck.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(response){
          alert(response.a);
       }
    });
}

saveFunction();
```